# How to intercep each line of stdout after issuing a command at prompt with python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have written a python script that is doing the flowing;

1. Connect to a LUN
2. Mount the drive
3. Backup my home drive to that LUN

All of the above is saved in a log file, everything is working as it should but I don't get what I want with the log file.

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from sys import stderr

logfile="/var/tmp/home-backup.log"
TimeStamp = datetime.now().strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S - ")
BackStamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
Portal = "192.168.1.59:3260"
Target = "iqn.2014-07.com.synology:fabdskst.linux-tgt1.888dddfd71"

File_obj = open(logfile, "a",0)

MyCommand = "sudo iscsiadm -m node --targetname " + Target + " --portal \"" + Portal + "\"" + " --login"
Discover = "sudo iscsiadm -d 0 -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.1.59:3260"
MyMount = "sudo mount -t ext4 -v /dev/sdc /media/linuxLUN01/"
MyBackup = "tar -cvzf /media/linuxLUN01/Mint_backup_" + BackStamp + ".tgz /home/fabrice/"

File_obj.write(TimeStamp)
subprocess.call(MyCommand, shell=True, stdout=File_obj, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File_obj.write(TimeStamp)
subprocess.call(MyMount, shell=True, stdout=File_obj, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File_obj.write(TimeStamp)
subprocess.call(MyBackup, shell=True, stdout=File_obj, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

File_obj.close()
```

I wanted to have every single line from stdout to be time stamped with the real time when the output come out to screen (in my case stdout is redirected to log file). Instead only the first output from a command is time stamped, the rest is not.

I am learning python so not I am not good (you might have notice that I don't do any testing at the moment, that will come later).

I was thinking on how to resolve this issue but I am only coming up with a non elegant solution that is not strictly exact in regard of timing;

1. I would save the start time at beginning
2. Save all output to a temporary file
3. I would save the finish time
4. I would count how many entries in the temp file and get the difference between start and finish time and divide the result with the number of entries ( (finish – start ) / count). This would give me an average time that I would use to build the real log file
5. Read the temp file line by line and transfer each entry like this (start-time + ((n-1) * averagetime) + “line from temp file” and increase n up to count for each line

Anyone with other idea that could make this more accurate? Ideally I wanted to intercept every stdout entry and add timestamps to it as it is coming out. Currently the backup take around 5 min.

Any advice really apreaciated

As requested by Ram here the extract from the log file

```
Sat 04 Oct 2014 22:15:04 - Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-07.com.synology:fabdskst.linux-tgt1.888dddfd71, portal: 192.168.1.59,3260] (multiple)
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-07.com.synology:fabdskst.linux-tgt1.888dddfd71, portal: 192.168.1.59,3260] successful.
Sat 04 Oct 2014 22:15:04 - Sat 04 Oct 2014 22:15:04 - /home/fabrice/
/home/fabrice/.gnome2_private/
/home/fabrice/.profile
/home/fabrice/.ICEauthority
/home/fabrice/.linuxmint/
/home/fabrice/.linuxmint/mintUpload/
/home/fabrice/.linuxmint/mintUpload/services/
/home/fabrice/Downloads/
/home/fabrice/Downloads/mshell.zip
/home/fabrice/Downloads/bash-4.3.tar.gz
/home/fabrice/Downloads/VMwareTools-9.2.4-1398046.tar.gz
/home/fabrice/Downloads/vmware-tools-distrib/
/home/fabrice/Downloads/vmware-tools-distrib/vmware-install.pl
/home/fabrice/Downloads/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/
/home/fabrice/Downloads/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib32/
/home/fabrice/Downloads/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib32/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1/
/home/fabrice/Downloads/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib32/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1/libgdkmm-2.4.so.1
```

You can see that only the first line of the output for each command get time stamped

As for stderr=subprocess.PIPE there is no particular reason why I use it I just put it there as it was on the example I found on the web, I still need to understand what it does.

Comment: Can you Post the output you are getting and please clarify why `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` is uesd in `subporcess.call` method ? because documentation suggests : Do not use `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include answers to your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a tested solution, but I belive it works fine:

```
import subprocess as sub

[...]

with open(logfile, "a", 0) as File_obj:
    for cmd in (MyCommand, MyMount, MyBackup):
        with sub.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
            while proc.poll() is None:
                log = [TimeStamp + line for line in proc.stdout.readlines()]
                File_obj.writelines(log)
```

*Obs.:* You want that stderr outputs to the terminal, right?

Comment: Thanks leogama,
Ihad to remove the second with statement as it produced errors. now my log look much better each of the three command produce its own real timestamp. The only small issue is that the tar command last around 5 min but all of the tar output get the same time, not to worry.

Comment: I can't really understand what you have done on your script but I will definitely look it up, you provided me with a great learnig tool thanks